# Mandatory many to many relationship in Django

Tags: python, sql, django-models

Suppose I've a model `Car` (cars are not owned, may be shared by passengers) and a model `Passenger` (passenger includes the driver of the bus).

```
# <app>/models.py
from django.db import models


class Car(model.Model):
    ...


class Passenger(models.Model):
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
    ...
```

The models are read/write able via [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and admin interface.

If I try to create a `Car` in the admin interface without referencing a `Passenger` I get notified `This field is required.` that's enough validation default behaviour for me. However via DRF during creation of a `Car` (POST) it seems like there is no way to assign a `Passenger`.

How can I enforce that each car has at least one passenger and potentially several passengers (mandatory many-to-many relationship) when creating a `Car` via DRF?

Answer (score 2):

At the database level, m2m relationships are materialized using an intermediate table having foreign keys on each end of the relationship. This means that you cannot create a m2m relationship between a given Car and a given Passenger before you have created both the car and passenger records (else you can't have the ids), and so you cannot prevent creating a car for the lack of a passenger.

In your example, you have at least one passenger that is "special", which is the driver. In this case the obvious solution is to have both a foreign key on passenger for the driver and a m2m relationship on passenger for the passengers. This way you can force the "driver" fk to be set, so you're sure you'll always at least have a driver.

FWIW there's absolutely nothing django nor python specific here, that's plain relational database design.

Comment: I never had this model design so I was not aware of. However it's totally logical. However in my case I have no "special" passenger. Consequently I cannot enforce at least one assigned passenger during creation of a car and have to validate somewhere else, in the application logic I guess... I integrate with a JS frontend via DRF. Where should I put the validation to?

Comment: RESTful APIs are state-less. How do I "enforce" or at least communicate to API users to create a passenger, create a car and update the car with it's passengers.

Comment: I adjusted the question. My problem remains w.r.t. DRF only now.